# CSS grid: fit a block into an empty space

Tags: css, grid-layout

I'm using a css grid generated with [grids.heroku.com](http://grids.heroku.com/) . For demonstration purposes I created a three-column grid. Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RamanChodzka/SE6wc/).

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container_3 clearfix">
 <div class="grid_2">
     <div class="grid_2 alpha omega highlighted" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Some content content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content </div>
     <div class="grid_1 alpha highlighted">
         1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
     </div>
     <div class="grid_1 omega highlighted">
         0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="grid_1 highlighted">
     Content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
 </div>

 <div class="grid_2 target">
         123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container_3 {
    background: yellow;
}
.highlighted {
    background: green;
}
.target {
    background: red;
}

/*grid css*/
body {
  min-width: 240px;
}
.container_3 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 240px;
}
.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3 {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.push_1, .pull_1,
.push_2, .pull_2,
.push_3, .pull_3 {
    position:relative;
}
.alpha {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.omega {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.container_3 .grid_1 {
    width:60px;
}

.container_3 .grid_2 {
    width:140px;
}

.container_3 .grid_3 {
    width:220px;
}
.container_3 .prefix_1 {
    padding-left:80px;
}
.container_3 .prefix_2 {
    padding-left:160px;
}
.container_3 .suffix_1 {
    padding-right:80px;
}
.container_3 .suffix_2 {
    padding-right:160px;
}
.container_3 .push_1 {
    left:80px;
}

.container_3 .push_2 {
    left:160px;
}
.container_3 .pull_1 {
    left:-80px;
}
.container_3 .pull_2 {
    left:-160px;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: '\0020';
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

**How can I fit the red block into the empty space in the second and the third columns?**

Here is a picture of what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

The columns can be of any height depending on content length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not particularly attached to grids.heroku and just looking for a styling work-around on a 3 column grid, here's one. It's much simplier than the grids.heroku spit-out code (it's less code and it uses classes like `size1of3` and `size2of3`) and it'll be much easier to change later if you decide to add/remove columns. Just a thought.

http://jsfiddle.net/2HyqD/

Comment: Looks nice. But what if the first column has little content? Like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RamanChodzka/2HyqD/1/). Adding `margin-left: 33%;` to the target column doesn't really help as the first column can have much content in it. Neither helps adding `.alignright` class to the target column as the third column (it contains "Content content " words inside) can be of any height.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `.grid_2` red block inside a `.grid_1` block.

http://jsfiddle.net/SE6wc/22/

Comment: How do I fix target column position, if the first column has little content? [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RamanChodzka/SE6wc/23/).
Seems that .push_1 on the target column doesn't help because the first column can have much content like in the original fiddle.

Comment: If this is going to be dynamic content I would suggest looking into a javascript plugin to handle this such as Masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com/) or Packery (http://packery.metafizzy.co/)